# Proper syntax or method for keeping url in modified isotope / category links

Tags: php, jquery, categories

I'm setting up a project gallery using isotope jquery plugin for layout and filterability.  I've seen examples of how to add a list of category links and modify them to filter on click, but...  I want to keep the url in the href attr, so that searchbots (or the theoretical non-js user) can click thru to project category pages.  My code works until I set up the $link variable and try to insert it into the html.  Yeah.... my php is weak.  How do I add the link to the href attr?

```
/**
 * Set up list of category links for gallery filter
 */
function galleryFilterLinks() {
    $categories = get_categories('exclude=1');
    $link = the_permalink();
    $html = '<ul class="gallery-filter">';
    $html .= '<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>';
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $html .= "<li><a href='{$link}' data-filter='{$category->category_nicename}'>{$category->cat_name}</a></li>";   
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use `get_permalink` (which returns the URL) instead of `the_permalink` (which prints the URL).</strike>

Try:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $link = get_term_link( $category );
    $html .= "<li><a href='{$link}' data-filter='{$category->category_nicename}'>{$category->cat_name}</a></li>";   
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gets the link of the current page, as opposed to the link of the cat page.

Comment: My bad, check revision.

Comment: You're the bomb! Note I also had to move the $link var down a few lines.  Thanks much!